# Why do you need to use React.Children to iterate children?

Tags: reactjs

this sounds like a bad question, but since `children` is already an `array`, while not call `.map` directly? is it just for catching case where children is singular?

-- Edit --
[image]

[image]

Comment: "is it just for catching case where children is singular?" This is correct. Since children can be an array, or a single node, you always have to check the type before calling `.map`. It's an easy check, but it gets duplicated hundreds of times in large applications, so React just provides a standard way to do it. that being said, you don't NEED to use it. Just a way to keep your code DRY

Answer (score 1):

Because children is not an array, is an opaque data structure, so that actually returns an array based on this.props.children

Here's the reference from the docs for more information.

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren

Edit:

In the case of your edit is acts as an array because it includes several children, but it could also act as other data types depending on the number of children or if it has children at all, just like Charlie Martin pointed in his comment.